# How to create a file list on Android with alphabetical case insensitive order?

Tags: java, android, case-insensitive

At the moment I use this to create an array of directories and files in the directory /mnt/sdcard.

This sorts the filelist in alphabetical order, but case sensitive.

I would like to have this case insensitive.

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/");
File[] files = f.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use File.isFile() to check which things are files.  See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

You can use the Arrays.sort() where you pass in a Comparator to make the comparison case insensitive.  see: 
[Arrays Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

You'll want to first split the array into 2 arrays, 1 for directories and 1 for files.  Then do the sort on each array.

Comment: I've already fixed my problem to seperate directories and files immediately after posting this question here. But thanks for that! Now I'll try to make it case insensitive.